# Append on first click and detach on second button click

Tags: jquery, function, append, detach

I have this Jquery function that on the first button click it is detaching #mainFTL and on the second click it is appending it but I would like the function to do the opposite thing.  First click append second click detach. Thanks.

```
<button type="button" name="mainFTLbutton" id="mainFTLbutton" class="btn btn-success btn-block">FTL - Full Truckload</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
      var p;

      $('#mainFTLbutton').click(function() {

        $('#mainFTL').show();
        if (p) {
          p.appendTo('.appendFTL');
          p = null;

        } else {
          p = $('#mainFTL').detach();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Then swap the functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // cache your selectors
  var main = $('#mainFTL'),
      btn = $('#mainFTLbutton');
  
  btn.click(function(){
    // check if the element is visible (it will only be visible when appended)
    if(main.is(':visible')){
      main.detach();
    }else{
      main.appendTo('.appendFTL').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#mainFTL {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainFTL">Hello</div>

<div class="appendFTL"></div>

<button type="button" name="mainFTLbutton" id="mainFTLbutton" class="btn btn-success btn-block">FTL - Full Truckload</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Then just lookup the element and set the variable.

```
var p = $('#mainFTL').detach();
```

Then the p will exist on the first click and it will append it.